# Show that $\{ x = (x_n) \in H^\infty: |x_k - y_k| < \epsilon, k = 1, ..., N\}$ is open in $H^\infty$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, hilbert-spaces

Given is $y = (y_n) \in H^\infty$, $N\in\mathbb{N}$, and $\epsilon > 0$, where $H^\infty$ is the Hilbert cube.

**Question:** How do I show that $\{ x = (x_n) \in H^\infty: |x_k - y_k| < \epsilon, \,\,k = 1, ..., N\}$ is open in $H^\infty$.

Before trying this exercise I never heard about the Hilbert cube. I now know that it's the carthesian product of the intervals [0,1/n], but I have no idea how to proceed from here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your description of the Hilbert cube is not correcct.

$H^\infty$ is the set aof all real sequences $u=(u_n)$ with $0 \le u_n \le 1$ for all $n$.

For $u,v \in H^\infty$  define

$d(u,v):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|u_n-v_n|}{2^n}$.

Then $( H^\infty, d)$ is a metric space.

Now let $M=\{ x = (x_n) \in H^\infty: |x_k - y_k| < \epsilon, \,\,k = 1, ..., N\}$.

Are you now in a position to show that $M$ is open in $( H^\infty, d)$ ?